Old HPE server, Ubuntu server running virtualbox?
Been using VirtualBox a lot on my Windows 11 PC for building Ubuntu servers for testing things and at work I have a couple of old HPE servers, that I would like to have setup with Ubuntu Server (which isn't the issue) but is there a way to install VirtualBox and build VMs with the desktop? Want to do this all completely command line, I don't want a desktop on the host at all.
Just never installed VirtualBox on Linux (gui or cli).
Cheers...
